# Strange Behavior of Eclipse When Debugging C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I've been coding with Java on Eclipse for around a year now and it has been working wonderfully. However, I recently installed C++ for Eclipse by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdisTzxTia0&t=200s) and I have experienced some issues while debugging C++ code.

The first issue is that when taking input while debugging, seemingly random values are assigned to my variables. Here is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1kbM.png

Another issue is, rather than immediately terminating at the end of the program, Eclipse takes me to another page labeled "_tmainCRTStartup() at 0x40137c". Here is an image of the page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENAUB.png

In this image we also see the first issue as 49 is printed rather than 10.

I would also like to add that the issues never occurred when I was debugging Java, or when I'm simply running the C++ code rather than debugging.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the C++ plugin, but it did not fix the issue. I have also tried searching these issues online, but could not find any relevant information. As such, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[Edit: the second issue has been resolved, but not the first]

Comment: _Another issue_: The end of `main` is not _the end of the program_; `main` is a function, called from somewhere and returning to somewhere; "_tmainCRTStartup() at 0x40137c" is that somewhere (in the C Run Time Startup code).

Comment: 49 should be the ascii code of '1' in decimal, you may start from this direction.